# How can I perform joins from both sides of the relation using TypeORM while avoiding circular dependencies in NestJS?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, one-to-many, circular-dependency

I'm using NestJS to build an API, and two of my entities look (partially) like this:

```
@Entity()
export class Site{
    @PrimaryColumn()
    SiteId: number

    @OneToMany(() => Truck, truck => truck.Site)
    TruckSystemID?: Truck[];
    }

@Entity()
export class Truck{
    @PrimaryColumn()
    SystemId: number

    @ManyToOne(() => Site, (site) => site.photos)
    Site: Site
}
```

So to recap there is a Site entity which has a OneToMany relationship with the Truck entity.

Now, let's say from my Truck controller, I'd like a way to do a get operation in which I only return Trucks which are related to a Site with a certain SiteId. I could do this as follows in the TruckService:

```
async findBySite(siteId: number): Promise<CreateTruckDto[]> {
    const truckEntities: Truck[] = await this.truckRepository.find({
      where: {
        Site: await this.sitesService.findOneEntity(siteId)
      },
      relations: {
        Site: true
      }
    })
```

But in order to have done with query, I had to import the Site service into the Truck service in the constructor:

```
    private readonly sitesService: SitesService,
```

I can do this by exporting SitesService in the SitesModule and importing the SitesModule into the TruckModule:

```
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Truck]), SitesModule],
  controllers: [TruckController],
  providers: [TruckService],
  exports: [TruckService]
})
export class TruckModule {}
```

Now this works all fine so far. But let's say I want to do a similar query from my TrucksController, where I'd like a method which only returns a Truck which matches a system ID I pass to it.

If I was to implement this in the same way I implemented findBySite in the sitesService, then I would need to call on the truckService within the sitesService. This would force me to import the SitesModule into the TrucksModule.

Now we have a circular dependency.

The standard prescription when dealing with a circular dependency is to:

1. Avoid it altogether
2. Use forwardRef() in the constructor to try to resolve the issue from https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency

I ask: in this situation, how could I avoid this circular dependency? Is it unreasonable to want to do this query from both sides of the relation? If not, is my implementation in which I need to import the services from outside the module I'm working in ineffective?

Let's say that the answer to the above two questions is no, and I'm approaching this implementation correctly, when I try using forwardRef() it doesn't fix the problem and the project still fails to compile complaining about circular dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know the answer to, if it is good practice or not. But, to solve the circular dependency error you have to implement the forwardRef() in controller.ts and modules.ts of both the truck and site module.
Instead of

in truck module

> imports:[SiteModule]
> use

> imports: [forwardRef(()=> SiteModule),]

same way around in the site module and export both there services.
I had the same error, this worked for me